# abs function for float returning un expected values C

Tags: c

I am having an issue using the abs() function with float values. It worked perfect when using ints but when using float it always just outputs 1, even when it should be e.g 3.1 - 1.8 was coming out as 1. I am using arrays to get the values, just unsure as whats going on, I tried using fabs and changing from float to double but no difference.

```
 x_distance = abs(x_coord[0] - x_coord[1]);
```

D:/Data D drive/University/Year_2/EEEE 2063/CourseWork2/test/main.c:33:18:

Comment: For working with real numbers (double) you should use the fabs function: https://www.programiz.com/c-programming/library-function/math.h/fabs
abs works with integers only

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: What you actually do is calling `abs` with `1` as `3.1-1.8` evaluates to `1.3` which is chopped to `1` when converting to `int`. As you can see in the spec, the function is defined as `int abs(int)` and cannot take or return anything but an  `int`. If you get a problem when you use `fabs` show what you put in and what you get. And... You did include `math.h` did you?

Comment: I thought that but i get this weird error using fabs "D:/Data D drive/University/Year_2/EEEE 2063/CourseWork2/test/main.c:33:18:"

Comment: Aside: don't use `float` unless there is a very good reason why you can't use `double`.

Comment: Please add complete error messages to your question, not in comments.

Comment: If you "tried using fabs and changing from float to double but no difference" then there is something else not shown. Please post a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), the shortest *complete* code that shows the problem.

Comment: That is not an error message but only part of it. This indicates where the error is located but as you don't provide a complete program, the line number is useless for us. The real error message is still missing. Is it something like "implicitely declaring function `fabs`"?

Comment: @WeatherVane: There is no reason to ask for a [mre] when the question clearly asks why `abs` does not return correct results for floating-point inputs. The answer is obviously that using `abs` converts the argument to an integer.

Answer (score 1):

`abs` is for `int` arguments. Using it with a floating-point argument truncates the value to an integer (or overflows).

Use `fabsf`, `fabs`, or `fabsl` for `float`, `double`, or `long double`, respectively. These are declared in `<math.h>`.

Alternatively, include `<tgmath.h>` (type-generic math) and use `fabs` with any floating-point type.

Answer (score -1):

I just realised I didnt include the math.h library as I thought it was defined inside the stdlib.h.
Thanks for your help everyone

Comment: `abs()` is in `stdlib.h` but `fabs()` is in `math.h`. Never leave compiler warnings unsolved.

Comment: It is important to look at compiler warnings and keep them = 0.

Comment: Not including `<math.h>` is only part of the problem. You need to use `fabsf`, `fabs`, or `fabsl` for floating-point (`float`, `double`, and `long double`, respectively), not `abs`, which is for `int`.